# Angular js $rootScope.$on is not being reached at all as if it never existed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I move the `console.log` above the rootscope.on it prints it, but for some reason it is as if the rootscope.on is not being reached at all:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      template: "<ui-view></ui-view>",
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      controller: 'loginCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'content/auth/login.html',
      requireLogin: false,
      authorized: true
    })

    .state('app.register', {
      url: '/register',
      controller: 'registerCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'content/auth/register.html',
      requireLogin: true,
      authorized: true
    });
});


app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

    console.log("redirecting");

  })

});
```

Comment: You aren't calling `$rootscope.$on`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually calling `$on`.

Change

```
 $rootScope.$('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

    console.log("redirecting");

  })
```

to

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

    console.log("redirecting");

  })
```